# How does sql server agent access the azure storage blob

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, azure, azure-blob-storage

Good morning all ,

I must configure an automated backup to an azure blob storage

in the backup script I have correctly configured the credential

now what right is needed for the sql server agent startup account to access the storage azure blob

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply using storage account and storage key ( its preferable to use SAS token but I will give a code for using storage key as I have been using one for my personal use)

I am using Azure Fileshare instead of Blob storage so you will need to make a few minor changes. I use powershell and Az module. then I call that using powershell.exe using SQL Server agent at cmd mode.

##assuming you are using on-premise or Azure VM SQL Server

```
##set location to backup file location

cd W:\backups\bakfiles

$storageaccount = 'mystorageaccount'
$storagekey = 'my//storagekey==' (you will find this option in storage account in Azure portal)
$stcon = New-AZStorageContext - StorageAccountName $storageaccount -StorgeAccountKey $storagekey
$Container = Get-AzStorageshare -Name "MyStorageshare" -Context $stcon
$currentfolder = (get-item .).Fullname
Get-Childitem -Recurse |where-object {$_.GetType().Name -eq "FileInfo"} |Foreach-Object {
$path=$_.Fullname.substring($currentfolder.Length+1).replace("\","/")
Set-AzStorageFileContent -Share $Container.CloudFileshare -Path $path -Source $_.Fullname -Force}
```